# Why is the gradient of `where(x > 1, log(x), 0)` nan?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-gradient

Why is the gradient of `tf.where(x > 1, tf.math.log(x), 0)` `nan` when `x` is `0.0`, but not when it's `-1` or `1`?

Minimal example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([-1, 0, 1], tf.float32)

with tf.GradientTape() as g:
  g.watch(x)
  y = tf.where(x > 1, tf.math.log(x), 0)

print(y)

dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x)
print(dy_dx)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([0. 0. 0.], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([-0. nan  0.], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: log function is mathematically undefined when x = 0 ? and limit is -inf only from one side.

Comment: Agree with @Pac0, just run `tf.math.log([0.0])` and you will see why.

Comment: Even if the gradient of `log` is undefined, why is the gradient of `where` `nan`? Note the `x > 1` condition and the `-0.` gradient when `x == -1`.

Comment: Sure, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187342/tensorflow-gradient-with-tf-where-returns-nan-when-it-shouldnt for further information